# I want to make more lines(Plot, Contourseries)

Tags: python, sympy

If I run this

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
from sympy.plotting.plot import *

x, y = symbols('x y')
f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')

f = 1/((x+0.3)**2 + y**2) - 1/((x-0.3)**2 + y**2 )
g = 1/sqrt((x+0.3)**2 + y**2) - 1/sqrt((x-0.3)**2 + y**2)

p0 = Plot(ContourSeries(f,(x,-1.5,1.5),(y,-1.5,1.5)))
p1 = Plot(ContourSeries(g,(x,-1.5,1.5),(y,-1.5,1.5)))

p0.show()

p1.show()
```

[image]

only narrow region is displayed.

I want to show wide region and more lines.

How can I solve? (picture is p0)

Comment: What do you mean with "narrow region" Are there lines that are not displayed here?

Answer (score 0):

You set your x and y limits to [-1.5; 1.5]. Select more consistent intervals for x and y:

```
p0 = Plot(ContourSeries(f,(x,-.4,.4),(y,-.01,.01)))
p1 = Plot(ContourSeries(g,(x,-.4,.4),(y,-.01,.01)))
```

[image]